# Spring security Preauth: how to pass user roles through customized authentication filter

Tags: spring, security, filter, roles

I'm new to Spring security, and working on a grails app that connect to external authentication and session management service for authentication/authorization. So what I did is create customized authentication filter

```
class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends  AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest  request) {
        //in here i call an external service, passing in the a cookie from the request, 
        //and get username and role information from the service
        //not sure what to do with user roles
         return username
    }
}
```

Then I looked at super class AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter code, in it's doFilter() method, it create an PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken (new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials);) for authentication, but it only takes username and credential, not the role information. Then I tried to inject a different details source J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource into the filter, because looks to me (i might be wrong) this detail source will pass the role information to the authentication object by calling setDetails(). but J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource is reading role information from http request object.

```
protected Collection<String> getUserRoles(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ArrayList<String> j2eeUserRolesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String role : j2eeMappableRoles) {
        if (request.isUserInRole(role)) {
            j2eeUserRolesList.add(role);
        }
    }

    return j2eeUserRolesList;
}
```

I got confused about the life cycle of authentication. I thought the http request object is getting role information through authentication object in security context, which hasn't been created at this point. I need the role information in order to create the authentication object. Isn't this running in cycle? or am I misunderstanding anything?

I know I can go with another approach to make my app work, just making my own filter to create the authentication object (which takes the role parameter) instead of letting super class (AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter) to create the authentication object, but I'm just curious why the first approach is not working. What is J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource trying to do? It calls request.isUserInRole(role), but by who and when is the user role set to http request?

Hopefully I express myself clear enough for someone to understand.